# trying to understand closure issue in js

Tags: javascript

Option 1:

```
function addLinks () {
    for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = function () {
            alert(i);
        };
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
}
window.onload = addLinks;
```

Option 2:

```
function addLinks () {
    for (var i=0, link; i<5; i++) {
        link = document.createElement("a");
        link.innerHTML = "Link " + i;
        link.onclick = function (num) {
            return function () {
                alert(num);
            };
        }(i);
        document.body.appendChild(link);
    }
}
window.onload = addLinks;
```

I know Option 1: will output 5 everytime you click because of closure, but Option 2 will output the right result, 0,1,2...

My question is: How does Option 2 resolve the problem? how does Option 2 work?

Comment: You might want to take a look at this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work). It has lots of useful replies to help you understand how closures work.

Comment: This may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable in Option 1, `i`, is at the scope of the function `addLinks()` (because it is declared as a var in that function).  It's only called once, there's only one scope shared by all five of functions assigned to onclick.

In Option 2, the variable `num` is in the scope of the anonymous function (because it is a formal parameter to that function).  It's called five times; there are five separate scopes, one for each of the five functions assigned to onclick.

Does that help?

Comment: +1 was going to write the same. In fact in #1, 5 closures are created, all referring to the same variable. In #2, 10 closures are created where as 5 refer to i but are immediately evaluated (immediate function). The 5 inner closures refer to 5 newly created variables with 5 different values.